# The SVG use tag not rendering gradients Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg

I have a javascript app (CAD like) build in SVG that have `tools` (objects build in SVG with Inkscape) that are inserted with the `use` tag. Everything works fine on Chrome and Safari (never tested in IE), but in Firefox, all objects that `fill` with gradients did not render. Like image below:

### Firefox

[image: Firefox]

### Chrome

[image: Chrome]

The `tools` are loaded like this (using external files)

```
<use 
  id="SvgjsUse1448" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  xlink:href="assets/images/neomap/tools/armchair.svg#armchair">
</use>
```

The gradients are defined in a separate `svg` inside the `html` page

```
...
<linearGradient xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="armchair_SVGID_1_" y2="1911.6" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x2="1201.2" gradientTransform="matrix(1.0799475,0,0,1.2039969,15.269894,2.997636)" y1="467.91" x1="1201.7">
```

and apply like this

```
<svg xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" height="100%" width="100%" version="1.1" >
  <defs>
    <symbol id="armchair" viewBox="0 0 72000 54000">

       <path style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:6.84171867;stroke-miterlimit:10;fill:url(#armchair_SVGID_1_);" d="m2234.8,743.7s168.9,1406.4,0,1487.4c-188.77,90.42-1655.6,92.708-1844.3-0.4817-168.8-83.316,0-1488.9,0-1488.9v-182.09h1841l3.2398,184.09z"/>
       ...
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

It's a bug on Firefox? How can I workaround?

Comment: Are the gradients defined in the symbol? If so don't.

Comment: @RobertLongson, I update the question with your doubt, I try with `symbol`, `g`, and even the entire `svg`, all worked on other browsers, except firefox.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and it turned out that mine was a real edge case, so I'm posting my solution here for the benefit of others.

My goal was to define a set of icons for later reuse in the document. I had defined the icons as nested svg documents inside a `defs` element:

```
<svg id="icons">
  <defs>

    <g id="atom-icon">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 256 256">
        <defs>
          <linearGradient id="atom-41-a" x1="50%" x2="50%" y1="3.961%" y2="100%">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FDFDFD"/>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#CBCBCB"/>
          </linearGradient>
          <linearGradient id="atom-41-b" x1="50%" x2="50%" y1="3.961%" y2="100%">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#B2E198"/>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#04A171"/>
          </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <g fill="none">
          <circle cx="128" cy="128" r="127.858" fill="url(#atom-41-a)"/>
          <circle cx="127.858" cy="128.142" r="116.907" fill="url(#atom-41-b)"/>
          <path fill="#F2F8F6" d="M100.453 110.097a221.783 221.783 0 0 0-3.988 6.382 164.44 164.44 0 0 1-3.684-11.377c3.73-.535 7.695-.957 11.874-1.249a224.886 224.886 0 0 0-4.202 6.244zm103.138 7.475c-4.132-3.967-10.04-7.602-17.558-10.804-14.926-6.356-34.918-10.474-56.295-11.595a234.82 234.82 0 0 0-7.529-.277C138.53 75.415 154.292 65.05 163.472 64.7c1.944-.074 3.576.31 4.854 1.141 4.296 2.792 5.488 11.453 3.189 23.166a4.267 4.267 0 0 0 8.373 1.644c3.953-20.137-1.576-28.497-6.911-31.965-2.785-1.81-6.093-2.655-9.83-2.513-14.12.536-33.904 15.592-51.956 38.803-7.148.247-14.038.864-20.483 1.827a106.106 106.106 0 0 1-1.625-9.522c-1.619-13.344.367-22.816 5.312-25.337.794-.405 1.662-.639 2.654-.713 4.418-.332 10.652 2.637 17.542 8.359a4.267 4.267 0 0 0 5.452-6.565c-8.85-7.35-16.8-10.817-23.633-10.303-2.112.158-4.095.703-5.892 1.62-4.593 2.342-7.732 6.828-9.33 13.331-1.368 5.57-1.562 12.513-.576 20.636.39 3.213.96 6.556 1.695 9.998-5.04 1.062-9.71 2.356-13.897 3.869-18.316 6.616-22.544 15.337-22.866 21.488-.308 5.876 2.7 14.62 18.775 22.91a4.267 4.267 0 0 0 3.911-7.583c-9.247-4.77-14.41-10.193-14.165-14.88.346-6.605 11.417-13.596 30.274-17.535 1.747 6.309 3.99 12.861 6.68 19.505-6.777 12.723-11.722 25.262-14.286 36.416-1.833 7.97-2.369 14.89-1.592 20.567.906 6.63 3.558 11.418 7.881 14.228 2.205 1.433 5.176 2.553 9.079 2.553 5.658 0 13.275-2.357 23.343-9.538a4.267 4.267 0 1 0-4.955-6.948c-9.925 7.08-18.454 9.613-22.816 6.778-4.652-3.023-5.633-12.642-2.624-25.728 1.995-8.678 5.555-18.296 10.383-28.21a220.995 220.995 0 0 0 3.283 6.731c9.717 19.087 21.612 35.694 33.494 46.762 5.984 5.573 11.708 9.497 17.011 11.663 3.218 1.314 6.24 1.971 9.045 1.971 2.596 0 5.008-.563 7.216-1.69 4.43-2.259 7.511-6.52 9.157-12.665 1.41-5.263 1.726-11.827.942-19.512-1.543-15.11-7.253-33.539-16.077-51.891a4.267 4.267 0 0 0-7.69 3.697c8.407 17.485 13.833 34.908 15.278 49.06 1.27 12.447-.78 21.31-5.486 23.71-4.942 2.52-13.756-1.438-23.58-10.588-11.17-10.404-22.43-26.168-31.706-44.388a210.555 210.555 0 0 1-5.851-12.483 210.936 210.936 0 0 1 7.143-11.836 213.301 213.301 0 0 1 7.877-11.333c.7-.01 1.405-.017 2.115-.019 3.664-.012 7.592.09 11.688.305 20.404 1.07 39.368 4.95 53.399 10.925 12.34 5.256 19.534 11.704 19.244 17.25-.246 4.708-5.967 9.575-15.696 13.352a4.267 4.267 0 0 0 3.088 7.955c16.905-6.563 20.821-14.967 21.13-20.861.27-5.151-2.04-10.111-6.865-14.743v.001z"/>
          <path fill="#F1F8F3" d="M119.194 129.133c0 5.153 4.174 9.33 9.323 9.33s9.323-4.177 9.323-9.33c0-5.154-4.174-9.331-9.323-9.331s-9.323 4.177-9.323 9.33"/>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </g>

  </defs>
</svg>
```

Which I used elsewhere in the document like so:

```
<li title="Atom">
  <svg><use xlink:href="#atom-icon"/></svg>
</li>
```

In order to prevent the big list of icons references from rendering on screen, I had applied the following styles:

```
#icons {
  display: none;
}
```

This caused, of all things, the url references to linearGradients to stop working. Probably the browsers removed them from the DOM tree because of display: none or some such effect.

The solution was the change the styles:

```
#icons {
  height: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this is exact my case.

Comment: Even if a parent applies `display: none` it will break any links in the svg!

Answer (score 4):

That's a Chrome/Safari bug you're relying on.

```
url(#armchair_SVGID_1_);
```

is actually shorthand for

```
url(<this file>#armchair_SVGID_1_);
```

but there's no gradient in the armchair.svg file.

The definition of what a base URI is is in [RFC3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986) section 5 which says

> Within certain media types, a base URI for relative references can be
>      embedded within the content itself so that it can be readily obtained
>      by a parser.

There's a [note in the CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#uri) referring to this which I think makes a clearer statement (at least for CSS since this is the CSS specification):

> For CSS style sheets, the base URI is that of the style sheet, not that of the source document.

The file armchair.svg defines a base URI the same as any SVG document or CSS stylesheet does, it's the absolute URL used to access it.

Webkit browsers get this wrong. There's [this bug for the CSS stylesheets case of this issue](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44047).

Use an absolute url or put the gradient in the use file (but not in the symbol part).

Comment: but in Chrome is everything ok, just firefox that doesn't render this. And the gradients is loaded inside the html.

Comment: Just because it happens to do what you want doesnt make it the right thing to do per the appropriate specifications unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

It's really a Chrome/Safari bug.
I figured out, that the problem goes away if you remove all the hyphens from the linearGradient elements' IDs. Simple as that. SVG then works with groups too (). 
I would be glad, if that helps somebody...

Comment: Don't work with Chrome 93...

Answer (score 0):

Firefox is behaving correctly [according to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#SymbolElement) for the SVG `<symbol>` element. With SVG any element that are nested inside a `<symbol>` element or `<defs>` element are not directly rendered with CSS, even with a `<use>` element. Only their attributes are. You are using the style attribute, which is CSS inside the `<symbol>` element.

You must use the SVG `fill` attribute directly to have it work inside a `<symbol>` element. Even though you are using a SVG `<use>` element. It is referencing SVG graphical elements inside a SVG `<symbol>` element with the CSS style attribute, which will not be rendered according to the spec, since the CSS display property does not even apply to the SVG `<symbol>` element.

This is not a bug in Firefox, Firefox honors the spec whereas Chrome and Safari which use webkit, do not follow the spec and allow it for now. But they will soon follow the SVG spec.

See these references and the spec:

W3C `<symbol>` spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#SymbolElement

> **‘symbol’ elements are never rendered directly;** their only usage is as something that can be referenced using the ‘use’ element. The ‘display’ property does not apply to the ‘symbol’ element; thus, ‘symbol’ elements are not directly rendered even if the ‘display’ property is set to a value other than none, and ‘symbol’ elements are available for referencing even when the ‘display’ property on the ‘symbol’ element or any of its ancestors is set to none.

MDN Firefox `<symbol>` element reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/symbol

> The symbol element is used to define graphical template objects which can be instantiated by a  element. The use of symbol elements for graphics that are used multiple times in the same document adds structure and semantics. Documents that are rich in structure may be rendered graphically, as speech, or as braille, and thus promote accessibility. **note that a symbol element itself is not rendered**. Only instances of a symbol element (i.e., a reference to a symbol by a  element) are rendered.

The spec states that SVG elements inside the `<symbol>` element are not directly rendered. In that case you need to change the actually attributes of those elements inside a `<symbol>` element or `<defs>` elements. So just change the SVG `fill` attribute instead on those elements inside the `<symbol>` element.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, this is a bug, but also an interpretation from the W3 Spec. In [this section](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermNonLocalIRIReference) is specified two types of IRI `local`, and `non-local`.

> **local IRI** references, where the IRI reference does not contain an  or  and thus only contains a fragment identifier
>
> **non-local** IRI references, where the IRI reference does contain an `<absoluteIRI>` or `<relativeIRI>` and thus represents a reference to an element *within the current document*.

What I see, is that Chrome/Safari are more flexible when dealing with the specification, allowing the `local IRI` to reference an external document, if it not exist in the current document.

The point is, Chrome/Safari doesn't render the gradients of an external SVG file (loaded by reference, in a `use` tag) that are at the same external file, only if the gradients are loaded in the current main html/xml `document`.

So, I create two files for each SVG tool, one for Firefox, and one for other browsers. And now another problem as came up, for low values of `transform: scale()` in a `g` element, or small SVG elements, the gradient disappear (transparent), and this I believe is a bug.

Comment: No, it's a bug. The Chrome developers accept it's a bug. When the current document is the armchair.svg file there's no linearGradient element to be found.

Comment: Sorry @RobertLongson, but your comment don't have much content to downvote my answer, even that it works for me. If you don't want to help, just sayng that "is a bug", just ignore this.

Comment: MY ANSWER IS BASED on the W3 spec, sorry, you invent your answer from nowhere (at least put some links to validate what you say), and downvote my because I just expose what are defined in W3 spec! There is a bugzilla similar https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=353575 that was open in 2006, and not solved yet, sorry but I don't buy this!

Comment: That's a different bug. You don't have a linearGradient element as a child of a symbol element in your markup.

Comment: "The Chrome developers accept it's a bug." → Does anyone have a link to this issue in http://crbug.com/ ? (I'm not challenging anyone's answer, I'm just curious and would like to "star" that issue.)